# Nullpointer exception when trying to create a deque in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, deque, doubly-linked-list

I have been trying to create a deque in Java, but I get a nullpointer exception when I add a new node. Here is the helper class I use for the doubly-linked list:

```
private class Node {
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;
}
```

Then I add nodes to the beginning of the list as follows:

```
    public void addFirst(Item item) {
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();      
    first.prev = null;
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
    oldfirst.prev = first;        
    N++;
}
```

I get a `NullPointer` exception for the `oldfirst.prev = first;` line. Also, when I compile the code I get the following warning:

`Warning: The field Deque2<Item>.Node.prev is never read locally`

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: If your deque is empty, then `first` may be null and `oldfirst` will thus also be null.

Comment: `Node oldfirst = first;` what is `first`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that `oldfirst` is null. And you initialise it as `Node oldfirst = first`, so it means that `first` is null.

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. And thanks to everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when your deque is empty, `first` is null. Then when you assign `first` into `oldFirst`, that makes `oldFirst` null, and so trying to access `prev` is giving an NPE. Changing the access to:

```
if (oldFirst != null)
    oldfirst.prev = first;
```

should fix it.

Your warning is probably just because you're not atcually using `prev` yet in your deque, you're just setting it. Fun fact: with a deque, you don't *need* a doubly-linked list, so your `prev` variable is unlikely to ever be used. If you also want to support queuing with your deque down the road (similar to how [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements both `Deque` and `Queue`) then you'll need to keep `prev`.